# Unix Shell scripting: how to modify output file names accordingly

Tags: shell, unix, scripting

So my current shell scripting is:

```
for j in *.jpg
do
  tesseract $j $j
done
```

where tesseract converts jpg files into text files.
With this script, if there was a file  HAHA.jpg, then the output file name becomes,
HAHA.jpg.txt          but I want it to be just HAHA.txt

Is there a way to make the output file name as HAHA.txt instead of HAHA.jpg.txt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this line after your tesseract  command:

```
for j in *.jpg
do
  tesseract $j $j
  mv ${j}.txt  ${j/jpg/txt}
done
```

Even though the tesseract has renamed your file, the variable `$j` will be containing HAHA.jpg.

Comment: Thank you !  could you tell me what the ${j/jpg/txt} line does?? I am quite new to shell scripting,, !

Answer (score 2):

If you have a shell variable `j` you can strip a suffix matching a given pattern as follows

```
${j%%.jpg}
```

Where `%%` indicates that the longest matching suffix should be removed and `.jpg` is the pattern ("a dot, followed by three letters: j, p, and g").

Comment: to strip any extension, you can use ${j%%.*}.

Answer (score 0):

Using basename:

```
for j in *.jpg
do
  tesseract $j $(basename -s .jpg $j)
done
```